# Changing background image with button

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

I am trying to make an application function so that when the user presses one of the images(which are buttons) the background will change. My issue is that when the button is pressed the background will not change to the picture. I have been trying to look for answers but have found nothing. Is anyone able to help? https://i.stack.imgur.com/boEiZ.png <- The image is linked here because stack overflow won't allow me to imbed images.

```
@IBOutlet weak var background: NSImageView!

let grass = NSImage(named :NSImage.Name(rawValue: "wetgrass"))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.
    background.image = grass
}

@IBAction func changeGrass(_ sender: Any) {
    background.image = grass
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your issue with current code?

Comment: try to fetch image from sender and set that to background.image

Comment: Sorry thought i implied what my issue is, but when the button is pressed the background does not change to the image.

Comment: Aren't you setting same image whether or not the button is clicked?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` does set the image already. So `changeGrass` will not change the background. I assume you put this in `viewDidLoad` to debug the problem and see if you can ever see the image, is that right?

Comment: i was trying to see of the image would load even without the button being pressed, it still does not load it in.

Comment: Could it be that `grass` is `nil`?

Comment: What do you mean by that Citetze?

Comment: [`NSImage.init?(named:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1520015-init) produces a `NSImage?` aka `Optional<NSImage>` -- that means, loading could fail. And `if grass == nil`, your assignment to `background.image` will simply remove the image (if there ever was any).

Comment: @Luke Kasper just replace my answer and make sure all button given proper IBAction so it will fetch image from sender and replace image of Background.

Comment: check if "wetgrass" image exists in your assets and don't forget to check any typo for image name

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a tested answer try this**

```
@IBAction func btnChangeImageClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let imageFromButton : UIImage = sender.image(for: UIControlState.normal)!

        imgBG.image = imageFromButton
    }
```

**Note: i make Any to UIButton in action so we can get image from that sender object**

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately I'm using NS not UI, they are work differently, one is for Ui ios programming while NS is for OSX. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes this is an OSX.

Answer (score 0):

How to approach solving the problem:

1. Find out if the assignment upon button press is the problem; isolate image-setting from the button callbacks. You did that already by assigning an image in `viewDidLoad` ✓
2. Find out if the image is broken.

The image loading could fail:

```
let grass = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "wetgrass"))
```

[NSImage.init?(named:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1520015-init) produces a `NSImage?` aka `Optional<NSImage>` -- that means, loading the image file with that name could fail. Use this initializer when you're positive that ...

- either your `Bundle` contains an image file named "wetgrass.png" that is copies into the app (check Build Settings > Copy Bundle Resources),
- or your Assets asset catalogue contains an entry with the name "wetgrass".

So `grass` could be `nil`. And if it is nil, your assignment to `background.image` will simply remove any previously set image (if there ever was any), resetting the `NSImageView` to display a boring gray background.

To **finally isolate and check if image assignment works**, use an image that's guaranteed to exist, like the built-in ones:

```
let testImage = NSImage(named: .advanced)!
```

Note I force-unwrap the optional here with confidence since `NSImage.Name.advanced` is guaranteed to produce an image :)

This should work then:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Show initial image:
    background.image = NSImage(named: .advanced)!
}

@IBAction func changeGrass(_ sender: Any) {
    // Show grass or another built-in image:
    background.image = grass ?? NSImage(named: .computer)!
}
```

So check your `grass != nil`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func changeGrass(_ sender: Any) {
    if let myButton = sender as? UIButton, let currentImage = myButton.imageView?.image {
        background.image = currentImage

        // Animated
        UIView.transition(with: background,
                          duration: 0.75,
                          options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                          animations: {
                            self.background.image = currentImage
                            })
    }
}
```